# Need help finding words in a list that contain a given character

Tags: c++, codeblocks

**The assignment is**:

> Write a program that reads an integer, a list of words, and a character. The integer signifies how many words are in the list. The output of the program is every word in the list that contains the character at least once. Assume at least one word in the list will contain the given character.
>
> Ex: If the input is:
>
> ```
> 7 red roses racecar room sunrise rock train r
> ```
>
> then the output is:
>
> ```
> red
> roses
> racecar
> room
> sunrise
> rock
> train
> ```

The code that I have so far is:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int len;
   cout<<"";  cin>>len;
   string inpt;
   vector<string> vect;
   for(int i =0;i<len;i++){
      cin>>inpt;
      vect.push_back(inpt); 
   }
   char ch;
   cout<<"";  cin>>ch;  
   for(int i =0;i<len;i++){
      size_t found = vect.at(i).find(ch);  
      if (found != string::npos){
         cout<<vect.at(i)<<"";
         cout<<endl;
         i++;
      }
   }  
   return 0;
}
```

But my output is:

```
red
racecar
sunrise
train
```

I would appreciate any help, please.

Comment: Remove the `i++;` from after the `cout<<endl;` Also not sure why you `cout<<"";`

Comment: @drescherjm I could not get the output to end with a new line any other way

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The final product

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int len;
   cout<<"";  cin>>len;
   string inpt;
   vector<string> vect;
   for(int i =0;i<len;i++){
      cin>>inpt;
      vect.push_back(inpt); 
   }
   char ch;
   cout<<"";  cin>>ch;  
   for(int i =0;i<len;i++){
      size_t found = vect.at(i).find(ch);  
      if (found != string::npos){
         cout<<vect.at(i)<<"";
         cout<<endl;
      }
   }  
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `<<""` in `cout<<vect.at(i)<<""` is unnecessary.   If having it is necessary, that's generally a sign of another bug (or you misinterpreting what is going on).

Comment: Yea I agree with Peter. Instead just write it like cout << vect.at(I) << endl;

Comment: @GregoryMcNeal when you post an answer to a question (ie, why doesn't this code work?), you should explain WHAT the solution is (ie, removing `i++;` from the search loop), and WHY it is needed (ie, because it causes the loop to skip the next entry in the `vector`). This is a Q&A site, answers should be useful to future readers who may run into a similar problem.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I apologize. I just wanted to help others who may find this post useful. I did not think of the consequence of giving the answer without explaining, and how that could affect someone in the future. I'll make sure to do better in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your Solution also be

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int len;
    char ch;
    cout<<"Input the length"<<endl;
    cin>>len;
    cout<<"Input the Words"<<endl;     
    char words[len][100];
  
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        cin>>words[i];
    }
  
    cout<<"Input the Character"<<endl;
    cin>>ch;
  
    cout<<"The output is :"<<endl;
  
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        int len_1=sizeof(words[i]);
        for(int j=0;j<len_1;j++)
        {
            if(words[i][j]==ch)
            {
                cout<<words[i]<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
    
      //The Output of above code 
    
      /*
       Input the length
       3
       Input the Words
       Sunday
       January
       Mars
       Input the Character
       n
       The output is :
       Sunday
      January
     */
}
```

Comment: That's the simple solution.